# Python multiprocessing pipe max write size

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe, pickle

I am implementing a piece of code using multiprocessing package of Python running on Ubuntu. For more efficient communication between processes, I'm collecting data to be sent through multiprocessing.Pipe in an array and send the whole array once size goes beyond 1000 elements.
I noticed there are occasional deadlocks in my code and seems like I'm hitting it where I'm sending batched data.
Tried a simple code to know if the size of the object sent over Pipe might cause deadlock and seems like to be the case.
After couple of rounds of experiments, it seems like 64KiB of pickled data is the magic number. Any number larger will cause deadlock and 64KiB or lower will go through instantly.
Documentation talks about 32MiB+ object sizes to throw exception. But my experiment shows 64KiB. Do you know if this is the case or am I doing something really wrong here?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
import pickle

c, p = mp.Pipe(duplex=False)

batch_list = []

for i in range(21912):
    batch_list.append(i)
    
print(f"Size of payload is: {sys.getsizeof(batch_list)/1024} KiB")
pkl_batch_list = pickle.dumps(batch_list)
print(f"Size of pickled payload is: {sys.getsizeof(pkl_batch_list)/1024} KiB")
p.send(batch_list)


while c.poll():
    try:
        c.recv()
    except Exception:
        print("got exception")

print("Done!")
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are doing something wrong. Only so much data (not well defined what this amount is) can be written to a pipe without blocking unless you are simultaneously reading from it. This would require that your "reader" is running in another thread or process so that writing to and reading from the pipe can occur concurrently.

Once your code executes `p.send(batch_list` it immediately blocks since nobody is reading concurrently from the pipe and thus you never get to execute your `c.recv()` call. In the following code we *first* start a thread that will read from the pipe:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from threading import Thread
import sys
import pickle

c, p = mp.Pipe(duplex=False)

batch_list = []

for i in range(21912):
    batch_list.append(i)

def reader():
    try:
        c.recv()
    except Exception:
        print("got exception")

    print("Done!")

t = Thread(target=reader)
t.start()

print(f"Size of payload is: {sys.getsizeof(batch_list)/1024} KiB")
pkl_batch_list = pickle.dumps(batch_list)
print(f"Size of pickled payload is: {sys.getsizeof(pkl_batch_list)/1024} KiB")
p.send(batch_list)
t.join()
```

Prints:

```None
Size of payload is: 173.84375 KiB
Size of pickled payload is: 64.0341796875 KiB
Done!
```

This problem does not occur if you are writing and reading from a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance, which is also implemented using a pipe but starts an internal thread that takes the data being put to the queue and sends it to the pipe. With such large data this internal thread will block until somebody reads from the queue but your main thread is not being blocked and so it can then ultimately issue a `get`:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
import pickle

q = mp.Queue()

batch_list = []

for i in range(21912):
    batch_list.append(i)

print(f"Size of payload is: {sys.getsizeof(batch_list)/1024} KiB")
pkl_batch_list = pickle.dumps(batch_list)
print(f"Size of pickled payload is: {sys.getsizeof(pkl_batch_list)/1024} KiB")
q.put(batch_list)


try:
    q.get()
except Exception:
    print("got exception")

print("Done!")
```